# AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: Main

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I get the error Fatal Exception main whenever I run my program. I have an activity cont
aining buttons for game levels. Whenever a button is clicked, the player is supposed to be directed to its corresponding level. But my program just stops working whenever I click on a button.(I have only started working on the porch level)

here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scr_levelboard"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Survival" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_porch"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_porch" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_livingroom"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_porch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_porch"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_livingroom" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnkitchen"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnbedroom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnbedroom"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_kitchen" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnbedroom"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_livingroom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_livingroom"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_bedroom" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnwashroom"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnkitchen"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnkitchen"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_washroom" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnbasement"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnwashroom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnwashroom"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_basement" 
    android:onClick="LvlSelect"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now here is my corresponding class:

```
package com.example.thesis;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;


public class Survival extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survival);

}
    public void LvlSelect (View view){
        if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_porch){
        Intent d=new Intent(this, PorchStartactivity.class);
        startActivity(d);}

        else if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_livingroom){
            Intent b=new Intent(this, LvroomStartactivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            }
            else if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_bdroom){
            Intent c=new Intent(this, BdroomStartactivity.class);
            startActivity(c);

        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my PorchStartActivity.class:

```
package com.example.thesis;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class PorchStartactivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer bgmusic;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new PorchGameView(this));

        bgmusic = MediaPlayer.create(PorchStartactivity.this, R.raw.bgm_housefly);
        bgmusic.setLooping(true);
        bgmusic.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        bgmusic.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

here's the logcat(sorry for not posting it)

```
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     ... 11 more
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.thesis/com.example.thesis.PorchStartactivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     at com.example.thesis.Survival.LvlSelect(Survival.java:24)
01-15 22:24:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(4170):     ... 14 more
01-15 22:24:15.369: E/Trace(5617): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Have you declared the PorchStartactivity at AndroidManifest?

Comment: @PM77-1 We should add a must-read Android FAQ which includes the requirement for these questions to include stack trace / logcat. Can barely remember a question which correctly included both code and logcat.

Comment: like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) @still_learning?

Comment: @Blackbelt No, beginners will never read that document and think "ah, I got to include the logcat". Anyway, off-topic, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent can't find "PorchStartactivity" class.

Declare "PorchStartactivity" activity in your androidmanifest

Also, other activities (levels in your case) needs to be declared in application manifest file as an activity. For more information why this is important, [read this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)